# File Transport Protocol for Maven

Tags: java, maven, deployment, repository

I usually use scp://server/path style URLs in distributionManagement config, but it is taking too long to deploy even small artifacts.

I have made a test using file://server/path style URLs, but it only works when I run maven from the same machine where the repository is.

Is it possible to use file://server/path style URLs to deploy to a remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

The deploy mechanism of maven is based on the wagon provider. The [file provider](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-file/) states in his documentation that he is only working for local file system. So I guess you need to test with the others ([wagon provider](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/index.html)). Maybe you can try with ftp if this is faster.

Hope this helps a little bit.